# How to publish solution with multiple projects?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an solution with two projects inside named App.UI and App.Processor.

I have set each of the files inside App.Processor to copy to output directory always.

However, I am unable to publish the solution. I have tried to build it to a Release folder and I copied the UI release folder into another computer to run it. The application could start and run but the back end which is done with App.Processor does not work at all.

How can I publish this solution properly?

### Edit

My apologies, there was some code left over from before that was preventing everything from running smoothly. Thank you for your help.

However, in my Release folder, there are plenty of files, is it possible to generate a standalone exe like Java?

Comment: First we need to know, what kind projects are these? Win forms? or what?

Comment: App.UI is a Windows form project and App.Processor is a class library

Comment: `App.Processor does not work at all` what does this mean?

Comment: You already doing the right stuff. Just make sure that all non-system references to "processor" are also set to **Copy Local**, unless they are in GAC on the target machine. Are there any event log errors?

Comment: Where can I see event log errors?  App.processors methods do not run at all. App.Processor will produce a text file but it doesn’t run in my release exe

Comment: Type in your Windows search box "event log". But I doubt you will find anything. When you say **"it doesn’t run in my release"** it doesn't mean anything. It is not producing the desired result but there could be 100 reasons for that and non of them have anything to do with wrong deployment. Pack your code with Tracing/Events and see what works and what not in release mode on target machine. You can write then as simple as `File.AppendLine` to a local text file, etc. I feel that you're looking at black box and trying to guess instead of actually trace the issue

Comment: When I run it from Visual Studio, my result text file appears in the designated directory. When I run the exe from the Release folder, it doesn't appear. To me that means that my App.Processor has not been run. I'm not sure what else I can do as it works in Visual Studio. Ill try tracing it and see.

Comment: Are you able to run the application from visual studio ? Can you share the code of how you are  using processor in ui project?

Comment: *"To me that means that my App.Processor has not been run"*. Exactly - to you! But to me, you don't know until you trace